# Set of rotations and translations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a normal subgroup of isometries group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the group of motions in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathcal{M}_+$ the subgroup of direct (also called "rigid", I think) motions.

I'm trying to show that $$[\mathcal{M} : \mathcal{M}_+]=2$$ and to conclude that $$\mathcal{M}_+  \triangleleft \mathcal{M}.$$

I thought about using Lagrange's theorem for the first part, from where I know $$|\mathcal{M}|=[\mathcal{M}:\mathcal{M}_+]|\mathcal{M}_+|,$$ but I'm not quite sure how to use it in order to get the result I'm looking for.

For the other part, I don't really know how to proceed.

Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the subgroup of rigid motions in the Euclidean isometry group $E(n)=O(n) \ltimes \Bbb R^n$ is given by
$E^+(n)=SO(n) \ltimes \Bbb R^n$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280141/rigid-motions-of-mathbf-r2-form-a-group). Now $SO(n)$ is a normal subgroup of $O(n)$ of index $2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025707/show-that-son-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-on).

See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group), where an argument is given before saying: "It follows that the subgroup $E^+(n)$ is of index $2$ in $E(n)$."

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{M}$ is the set of products of finitely many reflections about lines(not necessarily through the origin). 
$\mathcal{M_+}$ is the set of all products of an even number number of reflections about lines. What you have to do is take a member $f$ of $\mathcal{M}$ and member $g$ of
$\mathcal{M_+}$ and show that there is a member $g'$ of
$\mathcal{M_+}$ such that $f o g=g' o f$. This result is an easy conequence of the fact that if $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are lines there exists a line $\ell_3$ in the pencil determined by $\ell_1 \text { and }\ell_2$ such that
$$\omega_{\ell_1}o\omega_{\ell_2}=\omega_{\ell_3}o\omega_{\ell_1}$$ where $\omega_{\ell}$ denotes reflection about the line $\ell$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't know how to conclude that the index is 2... could you please elaborate a bit further? :)

Comment: @SantiMontouliu: Take a particular line L, say x=0 but it doesn't matter. Any member f of M is either the product of an even number of reflections, in which case it belongs to M+, or is the product of an odd number of reflections. Let g be reflection about L. Note that gog is the identity. If f is the product of an odd number of reflections, then f=g0(gof) so f belongs to g0M+. Thus M is the union of M+ and the coset g0M+., so M/M+ has exactly 2 members.

Comment: Super clear now, thanks!